# WIX bootstrapper per User

Tags: c#, wix

Using WiX 3.8. I've created an MSI that should be installed per User account. I've chained that .msi with other prerequisits within bootstrapper project. However, during an installation of produced .exe file I've prompted for Admin rights. When I enter admin user/pass the app is installed under Admin account and not the user's. If I install the .msi package alone then the app correctly registers under User account. Any idea how to deal with it ?

MSI package

```
 <Package InstallerVersion="500"
              Compressed="yes"
              InstallScope="perUser" />
```

Bootstrapper

```
<Chain>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="Netfx4Full"/>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="OpenXMLSDK"/>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="SQLServerCompact_4.0"/>
      <MsiPackage Id="MyApp" SourceFile="$(var.MyAddin.TargetPath)"/>
     </Chain>
  </Bundle>
```

Comment: Your `<Package>` has `InstallScope="perUser"` then why `ForcePerMachine` of `<MsiPackage>` is `yes` (with `InstallerVersion` set to `200` instead of `500`)? Explanation: I'm thinking about [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dd408068.aspx).

Comment: I'm not sure and I don't have SDK here to test but I'd first change `InstallerVersion` to `500`. AFAIK `InstallScope="perUser"` (because it'll set `MSIINSTALLPERUSER` to `1`) is supported only from version 5.0. Moreover if `<MsiPackage>` is your WiX project (the one that should be installed `perUser`) then why you set to `ForcePerMachine`? Shouldn't be let to default `no`?

Comment: As per your suggestion InstallerVersion="500" and ForcePerMachine is removed.. hence it is set by default to "no". But the problem still persists

Comment: Question: without Netfx4Full (which requires, of course, admin rights) do you have same issue?

Comment: I have to install it either way, can you explainpls  why do you think this is an issue? I have to install other libs as well as you see and they certainly need admin rights also.

Comment: I'm not sure about this so take it as something to check but: when netfx4full (or another) is elevated then all _transaction_ is elevated (and it won't rollback).

Comment: So, despite the fact that msi are set to perUser they are overriden by other prerequisites? The funny thing is, if I run for the 2nd time the installer it registers correctly under the User account.

Comment: That sort of makes sense. Installing .Net Framework must be done for all users. But after it is installed it does not need to be installed again.

Comment: Still, as you mention .NET framework is installed for all users however, the app is installed only for Admin. The current solution for me is actually change chain order. however if user miss some of the pre-requisites then the app will be installed under the admin also..

Comment: @Jim yes, I agree _per user_ shouldn't be affected by prerequisites. You install them with admin rights but app is just installed for current (unelevated) user. I don't know if it's a bug or a technical limitation in MSI or in prerequisite itself (as for WiX 3.0 with `limited` installation). Maybe if you don't make your `<chain>` a single transaction (as it was on WI hmmmm 4.0? 4.5? Can't remember) then they won't be _aggregated_.

Comment: If you could advice how to break the chain in multiple transaction (a) main app (b) prerequisetes I would really appreciate. And also pls make your comment as answer so I can accept it:) thx a bunch

Comment: Sounds that you have something that writes on places that require elevation. Maybe you can post more of your code, especially your Directory structure. When you build do you get any ICE warning?

Comment: I do actually, I am installing the app in ProgramFiles and its causing this.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to update your msi accordingly. On this [Wix-User's thread](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/dual-purpose-installer-ALLUSERS-2-and-Bootstrapper-td7591740.html#a7591809), you may find some good discussion upon Per-Machine or Per-User in context with Bootstrapper.

In addition this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dd408068.aspx) might give you some idea about your issue.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your `MsiPackage` cannot be the reason for requesting admin rights, probably the issue with outer `PackageGroupRef`s check for the admin's markers like secure properties of `PerMachine="yes"`